# how to save the output data in new column in csv file each tick in NetLogo

Tags: csv, netlogo

I need to save the data of my simulation in csv output file in netlogo 
each 10 ticks i want to save the data of several agents 
but I want to write the data in new column each time 
the problem that each time he continue wirting to new raws 
is there a command or a way to do that? 
thank you
and here is the function of writing to the file
and i call it in go procedure each tick

```
    to write-to-file [set-breed]
let n 0
let str ""
set str set-breed
  file-print (word "---------- Tick Number: " ticks "-----------") 
  foreach my-agent-list [
         ifelse ? != nobody[
         ask ? [
    file-print (word   ": (x:y)," "(" pxcor ":"  pycor"),")    
    file-type (word   ": age," age ",")
        file-print ""
     set n n + 1
    ]][
      file-type (word set-breed n ":," "dead")
      set n n + 1
       file-print "" 
       ]]   
  file-print ""  ;; blank line
  file-flush
end
```

and I get the result as following

```
---------- Tick Number: 0-----------
  pxcor: -70 pycor: -45 age: 0
  pxcor: -61 pycor: 42 age: 0
  pxcor: -91 pycor: -16 age: 0

---------- Tick Number: 1-----------
  pxcor: -70 pycor: -45 age: 1
  pxcor: -61 pycor: 42 age: 1
```

the desired would look as:

```
 ---------- Tick Number: 0---------     ---------- Tick Number: 1--- 
 pxcor: -70 pycor: -45 age: 0             pxcor: -70 pycor: -45 age: 1
 pxcor: -61 pycor: 42 age: 0              pxcor: -61 pycor: 42 age: 1
 pxcor: -91 pycor: -16 age: 0            pxcor: -91 pycor: -16 age: 0
```

Comment: Have you made an attempt?

Comment: Add any supplemental code to your question, not the comments.

Comment: What would your desired output look like in this case?

Answer (score 1):

File I/O is always going to be by line, not column, in our universe.  But you can take advantage of Open Office spreadsheet (or excel, if yo must) and in one step convert:

```
a,b,c,d,
Tick 1,5,4,2,
Tick 2,2,3,2,
Tick 3,3,5,-9,
Tick 4,3,-9,2,
```

into this, which is what I think you want:

```
a,Tick 1,Tick 2,Tick 3,Tick 4
b,5,2,3,3
c,4,3,5,-9
d,2,2,-9,2
```

by opening the csv file, copying the data to the clipboard, then Paste Special, checking the transpose option.